Pytest command doesn't work without specifying python -m pytest
My Project setup is in VS code and is as good as any setup. When I run python -m pytest testfile.py, everything runs smoothly. But when I try pytest test_file.py, it raises: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Library' pointing to one of the folders I've created as part of my framework.
Improper fix 1:
My search for similar issues led me in believing adding __init__.py in all folders (hence making them directories) would fix the issue. But, I tried adding it in all folders and that didn't help. (Later, as suggested by some other people I removed __init__.py files too. That didn't work either)
Improper fix 2:
Some suggested that creating a vscode file: vscode.env in the root folder and adding a variable PYTHONPATH = <test_files_path>. That didn't work either.
My pip and locust commands are working without having to write python -m <module_name>. What's the reason behind this behaviour with the pytest module?

Your question is:

What's the reason behind this behaviour with the pytest module?

The reason is literal - python -m adds current working directory to PYTHONPATH automatically, which is documented at https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m :

As with the -c option, the current directory will be added to the start of sys.path.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path .
In contrast, running a script with python executable, like python script or ./script with #!/usr/bin/env python, like pytest, does not add current working directory to PYTHONPATH.
Bottom line, you should interest yourself in https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules . Typically I install the project in editable mode before testing, i.e. tests expect the project to be installed.

Thank Kamil, I learnt a lot of things from your link. But I don't know if the document mention anywhere as to how "python -m pytest" can be shortened into just pytest. Am I missing something? Also, recently, when I recreated this setup in Pycharm (with proper python packages). There pytest worked without a hiccup. Why isn't the same thing happening with vs code?

I do not follow. Inspect PYTHONPATH on startup. It's easy - vscode or pycharm sets or does not set PYTHONPATH to the project. python -m pytest is not equal to pytest.

I couldn't figure out how exactly to inspect PYTHONPATH. But I opened the PyCharm created project now in VS Code and it's working. I guess we have to create proper Python Packages (not directories) while creating a project. Then it'll work. But it'll be helpful if you could tell me how to inspect the PYTHONPATH. I tried putting it in the Watch window of debugging. That didn't help

Try renaming your file to "test_filename.py" and your functions to "test_functionname"
Pytest docs states:

In general, pytest is invoked with the command pytest (see below for
other ways to invoke pytest). This will execute all tests in all files
whose names follow the form test_*.py or \*_test.py in the current
directory and its subdirectories. More generally, pytest follows
standard test discovery rules.

You can read the complete doc page here.

Hi Narguis, I'm sorry to have misspelled the file naming convention. I've edited it in the question. But I can assure you that wasn't the issue as I am using the right conventions here. I'm pretty sure it has to do something with my pytest path or something on the similar lines.

Oh, i see. In this case, i'm assuming you have a broken import of Library? Try running pip list and see if you find anything abnormal, such as Library 0.0.0. If that is the case, try adding this
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
before your imports on whatever you're trying to run
